# Segmentation Fault when using vmovupd

Tags: assembly, 64-bit, nasm, avx

I am trying to input four flouting point numbers at time into the stack then transfer it into a ymm(avx) register. A friend of mine is working on the same project and our code seems identical but I'm getting a core dump when I call vmovupd ymm0, [rsp]. I narrowed it down to that call with a debug program.

```
;===== Begin code area ====================================================================================================================================================

%include "debug.inc"

extern printf                                               ;External C++ function for writing to standard output device

extern scanf                                                ;External C++ function for reading from the standard input device

global intrest_calc                                         ;This makes trapezoid_area callable by functions outside of this file.

segment .data                                               ;Place initialized data here

;===== Declare some messages ==============================================================================================================================================

initialmessage db "Welcome to the Bank of Catalina Island", 10, 0

officer db "William Murmann, Cheif Loan Officer: ", 0

rate db "Please enter the current interest rate as a float number: ", 0

months db "Please enter the the time in months for the loan: ", 0

amounts db "Please enter the amounts of the four loans:", 0


xsavenotsupported.notsupportedmessage db "The xsave instruction and the xrstor instruction are not supported in this microprocessor.", 10
                                      db "However, processing will continue without backing up state component data", 10, 0

goodbye db "Have a nice day.  Enjoy your trapezoids.  ", 10, 0

stringformat db "%s", 0                                     ;general string format

fourfloatformat db "%lf %lf %lf %lf",0              ;four float format

xsavenotsupported.stringformat db "%s", 0

eight_byte_format db "%lf", 0                               ;general 8-byte float format

segment .bss                                                ;Place un-initialized data here.

align 64                                                    ;Insure that the inext data declaration starts on a 64-byte boundar.
backuparea resb 832                                         ;Create an array for backup storage having 832 bytes.

;===== Begin executable instructions here =================================================================================================================================

segment .text                                               ;Place executable instructions in this segment.

intrest_calc:                                               ;Entry point.  Execution begins here.

;=========== Back up all the GPRs whether used in this program or not =====================================================================================================

push       rbp                                              ;Save a copy of the stack base pointer
mov        rbp, rsp                                         ;We do this in order to be 100% compatible with C and C++.
push       rbx                                              ;Back up rbx
push       rcx                                              ;Back up rcx
push       rdx                                              ;Back up rdx
push       rsi                                              ;Back up rsi
push       rdi                                              ;Back up rdi
push       r8                                               ;Back up r8
push       r9                                               ;Back up r9
push       r10                                              ;Back up r10
push       r11                                              ;Back up r11
push       r12                                              ;Back up r12
push       r13                                              ;Back up r13
push       r14                                              ;Back up r14
push       r15                                              ;Back up r15
pushf                                                       ;Back up rflags


;==========================================================================================================================================================================
;===== Begin State Component Backup =======================================================================================================================================
;==========================================================================================================================================================================

;=========== Before proceeding verify that this computer supports xsave and xrstor ========================================================================================
;Bit #26 of rcx, written rcx[26], must be 1; otherwise xsave and xrstor are not supported by this computer.
;Preconditions: rax holds 1.
mov        rax, 1

;Execute the cpuid instruction
cpuid

;Postconditions: If rcx[26]==1 then xsave is supported.  If rcx[26]==0 then xsave is not supported.

;=========== Extract bit #26 and test it ==================================================================================================================================

and        rcx, 0x0000000004000000                          ;The mask 0x0000000004000000 has a 1 in position #26.  Now rcx is either all zeros or
                                                            ;has a single 1 in position #26 and zeros everywhere else.
cmp        rcx, 0                                           ;Is (rcx == 0)?
je         xsavenotsupported                                ;Skip the section that backs up state component data.

;========== Call the function to obtain the bitmap of state components ====================================================================================================

;Preconditions
mov        rax, 0x000000000000000d                          ;Place 13 in rax.  This number is provided in the Intel manual
mov        rcx, 0                                           ;0 is parameter for subfunction 0

;Call the function
cpuid                                                       ;cpuid is an essential function that returns information about the cpu

;Postconditions (There are 2 of these):

;1.  edx:eax is a bit map of state components managed by xsave.  At the time this program was written (2014 June) there were exactly 3 state components.  Therefore, bits
;    numbered 2, 1, and 0 are important for current cpu technology.
;2.  ecx holds the number of bytes required to store all the data of enabled state components. [Post condition 2 is not used in this program.]
;This program assumes that under current technology (year 2014) there are at most three state components having a maximum combined data storage requirement of 832 bytes.
;Therefore, the value in ecx will be less than or equal to 832.

;Precaution: As an insurance against a future time when there will be more than 3 state components in a processor of the X86 family the state component bitmap is masked to
;allow only 3 state components maximum.

mov        r15, 7                                           ;7 equals three 1 bits.
and        rax, r15                                         ;Bits 63-3 become zeros.
mov        r15, 0                                           ;0 equals 64 binary zeros.
and        rdx, r15                                         ;Zero out rdx.

;========== Save all the data of all three components except GPRs =========================================================================================================

;The instruction xsave will save those state components with on bits in the bitmap.  At this point edx:eax continues to hold the state component bitmap.

;Precondition: edx:eax holds the state component bit map.  This condition has been met by the two pops preceding this statement.
xsave      [backuparea]                                     ;All the data of state components managed by xsave have been written to backuparea.

push qword -1                                               ;Set a flag (-1 = true) to indicate that state component data were backed up.
jmp        startapplication

;========== Show message xsave is not supported on this platform ==========================================================================================================
xsavenotsupported:

mov        rax, 0
mov        rdi, .stringformat
mov        rsi, .notsupportedmessage                        ;"The xsave instruction is not suported in this microprocessor.
call       printf

push qword 0                                                ;Set a flag (0 = false) to indicate that state component data were not backed up.

;==========================================================================================================================================================================
;===== End of State Component Backup ======================================================================================================================================
;==========================================================================================================================================================================


;==========================================================================================================================================================================
startapplication: ;===== Begin the application here: Trapezoid area calculation =======================================================================================
;==========================================================================================================================================================================

;=========== Show the initial message =====================================================================================================================================

mov qword  rax, 0                                           ;No data from SSE will be printed
mov        rdi, stringformat                                ;"%s"
mov        rsi, initialmessage                              ;
call       printf                                           ;Call a library function to make the output

;=========== Show the officier name =====================================================================================================================================

mov qword  rax, 0                                           ;No data from SSE will be printed
mov        rdi, stringformat                                ;"%s"
mov        rsi, officer                                     ;
call       printf                                           ;Call a library function to make the output


;=========== Prompt for the rate =============================================================================================================================

mov qword  rax, 0                                           ;No data from SSE will be printed
mov        rdi, stringformat                                ;"%s"
mov        rsi, rate                                        ;"Enter the rate: "
call       printf                                           ;Call a library function to make the output


;===== Obtain the first base number from the standard input device and store a copy in xmm15 =============================================================================

push qword 0                                                ;Reserve 8 bytes of storage for the incoming number
mov qword  rax, 0                                           ;SSE is not involved in this scanf operation
mov        rdi, eight_byte_format                           ;"%lf"
mov        rsi, rsp                                         ;Give scanf a point to the reserved storage
call       scanf                                            ;Call a library function to do the input work
movsd      xmm15, [rsp]                                     ;Copy the inputted number to xmm15
pop        rax                                              ;Make free the storage that was used by scanf

;=========== Prompt for the amounts =============================================================================================================================

mov qword  rax, 0                                           ;No data from SSE will be printed
mov        rdi, stringformat                                ;"%s"
mov        rsi, amounts                                     ;"Enter the other base number: "
call       printf                                           ;Call a library function to make the output

;=========== Obtain the amounts =============================================================================================================================



push qword 0
push qword 0
push qword 0
push qword 0

mov rax,0
mov rdi, fourfloatformat
mov rsi, rsp
add rdx, rsp
mov rdx, 8
mov rcx, rsp
add rcx, 16
mov r8, rsp
add r8, 24
call scanf

vmovupd ymm0, [rsp]

pop rax
pop rax
pop rax
pop rax

;=========== Prompt for the amounts =============================================================================================================================

mov qword  rax, 0                                           ;No data from SSE will be printed
mov        rdi, stringformat                                ;"%s"
mov        rsi, amounts                                     ;"Enter the other base number: "
call       printf                                           ;Call a library function to make the output


;===== Retrieve a copy of the quotient that was backed up earlier =========================================================================================================

pop        r14                                              ;A copy of the quotient is in r14 (temporary storage)

;Now the stack is in the same state as when the application area was entered.  It is safe to leave this application area.


;==========================================================================================================================================================================
;===== Begin State Component Restore ======================================================================================================================================
;==========================================================================================================================================================================

;===== Check the flag to determine if state components were really backed up ==============================================================================================

pop        rbx                                              ;Obtain a copy of the flag that indicates state component backup or not.
cmp        rbx, 0                                           ;If there was no backup of state components then jump past the restore section.
je         setreturnvalue                                   ;Go to set up the return value.

;Continue with restoration of state components;

;Precondition: edx:eax must hold the state component bitmap.  Therefore, go get a new copy of that bitmap.

;Preconditions for obtaining the bitmap from the cpuid instruction
mov        rax, 0x000000000000000d                          ;Place 13 in rax.  This number is provided in the Intel manual
mov        rcx, 0                                           ;0 is parameter for subfunction 0

;Call the function
cpuid                                                       ;cpuid is an essential function that returns information about the cpu

;Postcondition: The bitmap in now in edx:eax

;Future insurance: Make sure the bitmap is limited to a maximum of 3 state components.
mov        r15, 7
and        rax, r15
mov        r15, 0
and        rdx, r15

xrstor     [backuparea]

;==========================================================================================================================================================================
;===== End State Component Restore ========================================================================================================================================
;==========================================================================================================================================================================


setreturnvalue: ;=========== Set the value to be returned to the caller ===================================================================================================

push       r14                                              ;r14 continues to hold the first computed floating point value.
movsd      xmm0, [rsp]                                      ;That first computed floating point value is copied to xmm0[63-0]
pop        r14                                              ;Reverse the push of two lines earlier.

;=========== Restore GPR values and return to the caller ==================================================================================================================

popf                                                        ;Restore rflags
pop        r15                                              ;Restore r15
pop        r14                                              ;Restore r14
pop        r13                                              ;Restore r13
pop        r12                                              ;Restore r12
pop        r11                                              ;Restore r11
pop        r10                                              ;Restore r10
pop        r9                                               ;Restore r9
pop        r8                                               ;Restore r8
pop        rdi                                              ;Restore rdi
pop        rsi                                              ;Restore rsi
pop        rdx                                              ;Restore rdx
pop        rcx                                              ;Restore rcx
pop        rbx                                              ;Restore rbx
pop        rbp                                              ;Restore rbp

ret                                                         ;No parameter with this instruction.  This instruction will pop 8 bytes from
                                                            ;the integer stack, and jump to the address found on the stack.
;========== End of program
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used the debugger wrong. Pay more attention.
The fault is not at the `vmovupd`, rather it is inside `scanf`. The reason is that you have 2 lines swapped in your code, hence the pointer argument `rdx` is messed up. I trust you can see the problem from this hint.

Furthermore, I can't find the counterpart to the `Retrieve a copy of the quotient that was backed up earlier`, and apparently neither can my cpu. As such, the stack is unbalanced and the return address will be corrupted.

Also, you don't seem to care much about stack alignment, which may bite you with unexpected segfaults too.

Comment: Thanks for the help, this is my second assembly program so still trying to wrap my head around it.